# ASP.Net Core 2.0 project for MacOS and windows

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing a school project with ASP.net core 2.0. I own a Mac and it is really great to use Visual Studio to create ASP.net core applications, but my partners have Windows machines. The thing is, if I create a repository and push my MVC project to GitHub, my partners can't open the solution from the repo, neither by cloning the project nor downloading the zip. If they create the MVC project in a new repo of GitHub using Visual Studio for Windows, I'm able to open the project in Visual Studio for Mac, but there is no compatibility with LocaDB so my program is not able to do a CRUD actions because of that.

Do you know if there's a possibility to work with .net Core while the team members have different operating systems? I mean maybe using the .gitignore or by doing migrations? Or do you recommend using only the same OS for Core 2.0 development?

Comment: "my partners can't open the solution from the repo" I wonder what error they are seeing. Not having experience with the matter myself, but highly curious, because I guess this should 'just work'. My first guess would be line-endings, but most of the time VS will be able to resolve this quite easily.

Comment: Use SQLlite instead of LocalDB. I suppose you may only have to update the following in the startup.cs and run the migrations process

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
            //services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            //});


          services.AddDbContext<MvcDWOLDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=MvcDWOL.db"));